# how to use public static int main (String args []) ? in Java

Tags: java, object, static, program-entry-point, public

can we use :

```
public static int  main (String args[])
{

}
```

and if yes, how to create ate object of the above method and execute using

```
public static void main (String args[]) ?
```

Comment: *can we use : public static int main ( String args[ ] ) {* - No.

Comment: Why would you want to return int?  If its for exit codes, use System.exit(exitCode);